# 253006 (n/a): File doesn't exist:

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

- I am trying to PUT a file into Snowflake staging area using PUT
  command.
- When I run the command using snowsql I am able to PUT the file in
  stage area.
- When I try to execute the same command from a shell script it is
  throwing below error.

**253006 (n/a): File doesn't exist: ['/home/raghu/sample_pipeline_config.csv']**

- Any help will be highly appreciated. FYI I am running the commands in
  **Ubuntu terminal.**

Comment: can you show the snowsql command and the shell script command. at a guess I would say you will need to escape some slash tokens as that is a standard scripting problem.

Comment: This can be related to permission rights on that file path.

Comment: Sincere apologies for the delay in responding back.
Thanks @SimeonPilgrim and Sergiu for getting back with your advises. Mounting the volume of the file in the docker image solved the problem.